# Colors in contours

Tags: plotting, color

When I want to draw a wide range of pictures,the  value     z=1 or     z=-1 corresponds to **plate patterns**,I want it corresponds to one colour.This problem arises only when the scope of painting is large.

Picture two is I want,but the range is too small.

For example xp values range from **0** to **10**,yp values range from **6** to **10**.The Program will cost your 40 minutes if your computer has 20 kernels.

---

*Interpretation by @Michael E2:*

I have a function $z = G(A,\omega)$ which normally takes two indicator values $z = \pm 1$.  The function is computed with a floating-point routine, so it does not compute these values exactly; also there are other values such along the left edge of the first image below.  I want to make an image of the plate pattern formed by the indicator values.  I expect to get an image mainly colored by two colors corresponding to $z = \pm 1$.  The first image is over the full range of `{xp, yp}`, but the image is a mess.  The second one shows the kind of pattern I desire, but the image is not over the full range.

On my machine (2.8 GHz 4-core Intel i7 Mac), evaluating `G[A0, ω0]` takes a little over a second on average.  The OP reports (I think) for a 20-core machine, a table of values over

```
{xp, 0., 10., 0.05}, {yp, 6., 10., 0.05}
```

takes 40 min.  If you change `dx = dy = 0.05` to larger values, you can reduce the time and examine a test case.  For example,

```
{xp, 0., 10., 0.5}, {yp, 6., 10., 0.5}
```

takes less than 60 seconds on my machine.

Is there a way to get uniform coloring of the regions?

---

```
t = 1; nk = 1; J = 1; Kx = -π/3; Kx1 = 2 π/3; 
Ky = -π/Sqrt[3]; Ky1 = π/Sqrt[3]; sp1 = 0.01; d = 30;

G[A0_, ω0_] := (
  ω = ω0;
  T = 2 Pi/ω;
  ClearAll[H, Hk, F];
  A = A0;
  H[k_] := H[k] = ({
      {0, 
       J BesselJ[k, 
         A] (Exp[-I kx] Exp[I k (-π/2)] + 
          Exp[I kx] Exp[I k π/2]), 
       J BesselJ[k, 
         A] (Exp[-I (kx/2 + Sqrt[3] ky/2)] Exp[I k (-π/6)] + 
          Exp[I (kx/2 + Sqrt[3] ky/2)] Exp[I k 5 π/6])},
      {J BesselJ[
         k, -A] (Exp[I kx] Exp[I k (-π/2)] + 
          Exp[-I kx] Exp[I k π/2]), 0, 
       J BesselJ[k, 
         A] (Exp[-I (-kx/2 + Sqrt[3] ky/2)] Exp[I k (π/6)] + 
          Exp[-I (kx/2 - Sqrt[3] ky/2)] Exp[I k (-5 π/6)])},
      {J BesselJ[
         k, -A] (Exp[I (kx/2 + Sqrt[3] ky/2)] Exp[I k (-π/6)] + 
          Exp[-I (kx/2 + Sqrt[3] ky/2)] Exp[I k 5 π/6]), 
       J BesselJ[
         k, -A] (Exp[I (-kx/2 + Sqrt[3] ky/2)] Exp[I k (π/6)] + 
          Exp[I (kx/2 - Sqrt[3] ky/2)] Exp[I k (-5 π/6)]), 0}
     });

  Hk = Table[
    H[j - i] + IdentityMatrix[3] If[i == j, i ω, 0], {i, -nk, 
     nk}, {j, -nk, nk}];
  Hk = ArrayFlatten[Hk];
  F[x_, y_] := (
    SA = Eigensystem[N[Hk /. kx -> x /. ky -> y]];
    SA = Table[{Chop[SA[[1]][[i]]], SA[[2]][[i]]}, {i, (2 nk + 1) 3}];
    SA = Sort[SA, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &];
    SA1 = SA[[1 ;; (3 nk + 1)]][[All, 2]]);
  s1 = Table[
    F[x, y], {x, Kx + sp1, Kx1 + sp1, (Kx1 - Kx)/d}, {y, Ky + sp1, 
     Ky1 + sp1, (Ky1 - Ky)/d}];
  s2 = Total[
     Table[Im[
       Log[Diagonal[(Conjugate[s1[[i, j]]].Transpose[
             s1[[i + 1, j]]]) (Conjugate[s1[[i + 1, j]]].Transpose[
             s1[[i + 1, j + 1]]]) (Conjugate[
             s1[[i + 1, j + 1]]].Transpose[
             s1[[i, j + 1]]]) (Conjugate[s1[[i, j + 1]]].Transpose[
             s1[[i, j]]])]]], {i, d}, {j, d}], 2]/(2 Pi);
  -Total[s2])
SetSharedVariable[ik];
ik = 0;
dp = Monitor[
   ParallelTable[{ik++; xp, yp, G[xp, yp]}, {xp, 2., 3., 0.05}, {yp, 
     9, 10, 0.05}], ik];
ListContourPlot[Flatten[dp, 1], Contours -> 100, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image: Picture one]

[image: Picture two]

Comment: "The Program will cost your 40 minutes if your computer has 20 kernels." I second what Kuba says. Most of us have only 2 or 4 cores, so what's the point? You may try to apply `Clip` and `Rescale` before plotting.

Comment: You can reduce the time by reducing the sampling considerably (to produce test cases, before committing to a high-resolution final plot).  What it shows is the almost 95% of the z differ from `-1` by rounding error, the differences being what cause the random-looking contour lines.  The other values (in my test case) differ from two other integers, `-5` and `1`, also by rounding error. Perhaps try `Round[G[xp, yp]]` in your table.

Comment: If your table runs over `{xp, 0, 10, dx}, {yp, 6, 10, dy}`, then this plot may be useful: `dx = 0.05; dy = 0.05;
Show[ArrayPlot[dp[[All, All, 3]] // Rescale // Transpose, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend["M10DefaultDensityGradient", #1] &), 
  DataRange -> {{0 + dx/2, 10 - dx/2}, {6 + dy/2, 10 - dy/2}},
  DataReversed -> {True, False}], FrameTicks -> Automatic]`

Comment: @guangya I tried to interpret your question.  Please check I have done so accurately.  You can fix any mistakes I made.

Comment: @Kuba I suspect what MichaelE2 suggested could become an answer if this is reopened.

Comment: Thanks a million.I really appreciate it,your said is right@MichaelE2